# Reapply for J1 Visa during current J1 program

Tags: usa, j-visa

When you receive a J1-Working Visa and currently work in America - Can you apply for a second J1-Visa in a different company/university to start directly after finishing your program of the first J1-Visa? I couldn't find any restrictions, but sometimes people say you have to wait for at least 2 years in your home country to be allowed to apply again.

Comment: The 2 year restriction should have been noted on the visa sticker and clarified to you, but verify at the international students' office (or whoever managed your visa process).

Comment: So there is definitely a 2 year restriction? I don't have my passport available right now - need to check later..

Comment: No, there doesn't have to be a 2 year restriction. There are cases where there is and there are cases where there is not. You'll need to check with whoever sponsored you what is the restriction, if any, in your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 12-month and 24-month bars if your new program is in the "Research Scholar" or "Professor" categories only (not other J-1 categories):

- If you were previously finished a program on J-1 as a "Research Scholar" or "Professor", then you cannot start a new J-1 as a "Research Scholar" or "Professor" again within 24 months.
- If you were in any J-1 or J-2 status for more than 6 months, you cannot start a new J-1 as a "Research Scholar" or "Professor" within 12 months after that.

Note: Don't confuse this with the INA 212(e) 2-year home residency requirement that some J1's have. That is a restriction upon getting an H or L work visa or permanent residency, which is irrelevant because you are not getting one of those.

Comment: Do you have any source? I couldn't find anything supporting what you wrote on the [J1 website](http://j1visa.state.gov/).

Comment: @Clément: http://j1visa.state.gov/programs/professor-and-research-scholar/