# Renew J2 visa without J1

Tags: french-citizens

I am a French citizen living in USA, my wife has J-1 visa, me and my daughter are J-2 dependent. All of Our visas expire in January. Me and my daughter we need to go back to France in February, but without my wife!!! So can I renew my visa and my daughter's visa if my wife stays in USA with an expired visa?

Comment: There's a question here at [Renewing J-1 and J-2 visas](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/8046/2440).  Does it answer your question too?